# [TeXstudio, OSX]: Check spelling pop up window displays garbled text in "unknown word" field

Tags: texlive, mac

I run TeXstudio on OSX, compiled from source. It has worked fine for a long time, but lately the spell check pop-up window does not work properly. This also affects older versions of TeXstudio (which used to work, I think). I do not know, for sure, but I am starting to suspect something outside the TeXstudio application.

The "Unknown word" field in "check spelling" is garbled. It looks like only the upper half of the field is updated with the new word. The lower half of the field remains as before, i.e. the old word is displayed. The result is a cut up of two words. Please refer to the example picture attached.

Am I the only one who sees this on TeXstudio using OSX?

[image: Example]

I have filed an issue:
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/283

How to reproduce on TeX Live using OSX.

1. Open LaTeX source file.
2. `Tools->Check Spelling`.
3. Jump to next word to be checked by pressing "Ignore".
4. Repeat step 3.) a few times

I do not see this if I compile the TeX Live source on Linux Debian. The Windows binary TeX Live also works fine.

`TeXstudio: 2.12.10 (git 2.12.10-73-g0ba02d02), latest git repo source as of 13 aug 2018`.

`Qt: Using Qt Version 5.11.1, compiled with Qt 5.11.1 R.`

`OS: OSX 10.13.6 uname -a.
Darwin Magnus-Larssons-iMac.local 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64.`

`TeX distribution: MacTeX-2018 (Texlive)`

What do you think? Any ideas?

Comment: seems to be a bug with TXS. if you have filed a ticket, IMHO there's nothing to be done regarding TX.SX.